# Issue with Footer CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

When I look at the site, here's a screenshot of it: http://prntscr.com/6epv7e
I'm finding it very difficult to add a space between the end of #site and #sitend.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: because you have  `fixed` footer

Comment: You're suggesting removing position:fixed; from #siteend?

Comment: Have you tried adding a margin to the bottom of #site or at the top of #siteEnd @MrRubbers

Comment: Yes, After you can add bottom margin to #site or top margin to #siteend

Comment: Awesome, that seemed to of worked.. how can I mark your response as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in many ways, please try these one by one:

[1] Use:

```
#site { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

[2] Use:

```
#siteend { margin-top: 20px; }
```

[3] use

```
#site { padding-bottom: 20px; }
```

[4] Use:

```
#siteend { padding-top: 20px; }
```

you can replace "20px" with any pixel value you like.

Comment: Thanks Tarun, I'll keep that in mind for the future!

Comment: For more responsive and mobile friendly webpage, you should use % (percentage) instead of px (pixels)

Comment: @MrRubbers don'f forget to mark this as the answer if it helped!